# react routing not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my roots defined like following:

```
<Route path="/" onEnter={this.verifyLang}>
  <Route path="/:lang" onEnter={this.verifyLang}>

    <IndexRoute component={this.getIndexRoute()} />
    <Route path="auth">
      <Route path="confirm-password" component={this.getIndexRoute()} />
      <Route path="confirm-code/code=:code&email=:email" component={this.getIndexRoute()}  />
      <Route path="confirm_email" component={this.getIndexRoute()}  />
    </Route>
    <Route path="landing" component={Landing} />
    <Route path="impress" component={Impress} />

  </Route>
</Route>
```

The function `this.getIndexRoute()` gives me Launch component. Now inside Launch component I have a method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    browserHistory.push('landing');
}
```

I am expecting to redirect to Landing component but nothing happens. Why it is so?

Comment: What version of router? Is that the react-router `browserHistory` you're referencing?

Comment: correct I guess it's less than version 3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31079244/438992 so if all else is well I'm not sure what the issue would be.

Comment: From the official documentation, `componentWillReceiveProps` is invoked when the `props` will be updated, not when the component is being initialized. Maybe you want to put it in `componentWillMount()`?

Comment: Well, I put in anywhere, the route remains the same!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of...

```
<IndexRoute component={this.getIndexRoute()} />
```

I would use...

```
<IndexRedirect to='landing' />
```

Refactoring your code:

```
<Route path="/" onEnter={this.verifyLang}>

  <Route path=":lang" onEnter={this.verifyLang}>

    <IndexRedirect to='landing' />

    <Route path="auth">
      <Route path="confirm-password" component={this.getIndexRoute()} />
      <Route path="confirm-code/code=:code&email=:email" component={this.getIndexRoute()}  />
      <Route path="confirm_email" component={this.getIndexRoute()}  />
    </Route>

    <Route path="landing" component={Landing} />
    <Route path="impress" component={Impress} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```